# Nature of the infinite differential sum operator?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

Consider the operator

$$ Hf = f + f' + f'' +\cdots = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left[ \frac{d^i f}{dx^i}\right] $$

I am trying to determine what

$ Hf $ is entirely in terms of $f$.

I note the following relationship:

$$Hf - f = Hf' \rightarrow Hf - f = \frac{dHf}{dx}$$

I let $Hf = A$

$$ A - f = \frac{dA}{dx}$$

This is a linear ODE with solution

$$ A = -\frac{\int e^{-x} f }{e^{-x}} \rightarrow Hf = -\frac{\int e^{-x} f }{e^{-x}}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Is there any real life application of this? I have no idea why i'm spending so much time on it, this is too addicting

Comment: That probably belongs on lifeadvice.stackexchange

Comment: How? $Hf' = (f') + (f')' + (f')'' ... = \sum_{i =0}^{\infty} \left((f')^{[i]} \right) = \sum_{i =0}^{\infty} \left((f)^{[i+1]} \right) = \sum_{i =0}^{\infty} \left((f)^{[i]} \right)' = (Hf)' $